# Vue JS Вывод таблицы из БД

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vue.js, axios

Нужно вывести таблицу из БД, полученную с помощью AXIOS

```
<app-table></app-table>

Vue.component('app-table',{

data: function(){

    return table;

},
template: '<table><tr><th>№</th><th>Адрес</th><th>Услуги</th></tr><tr v-for="str in table"><td>{{ str.id }}</td><td>{{ str.address }}</td><td>{{ str.priceList }}</td></tr></table>'
```

});

var dentistriesControl = new Vue({
el: '#dentistriesControl',
data: {
show: false,
table: []
},
methods: {

```
    }
}
```

});

Данные хранятся в table.
Происходит ошибка, таблица отрисовывается вместе с заголовком, но данные не выводятся:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: table is not defined"
```

found in

---> 

ReferenceError: table is not defined
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "table" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Возможно не работает из за того  что в table почему то преобразовывется в https://yadi.sk/i/kaqHSwnp2jSC7g , при попытке перезаписи через циклы в массив, всё  равно observer

Answer (score 1):

Вы возвращаете в методе `data()` уже сами данные из переменной table, в которых разумеется нету ключа `table` который вы пытаетесь испоьзовать в `v-for`

```
data: function(){
    return {
        table: table,
    };
},
```